# Filter unique distinct values using first 3 digit vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I need to filter the phone number by the cell operator in vb.net
example:

- operator 1 first 3 digit 811
- operator 2 first 3 digit 812
- operator 3 first 3 digit 822

from this

- 8113634563
- 8122345235
- 8226786767

to this

- operator 1 first 3 digit 811 8113634563
- operator 2 first 3 digit 812 8122345235
- operator 3 first 3 digit 822 8226786767

Comment: What do you want to do if you get more than one phone number starting with the same three characters, say 8113634563 and 8112222222 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this example:

```
    Sub Main()
        Dim phones As String() = {"8113634563", "8113777763", "8122345235", "8226786767"}

        Dim s As Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String)) = phones.GroupBy(Function(ph) ph.Substring(0, 3)).ToDictionary(Function(g) g.Key, Function(g) g.Select(Function(p) p).ToList)

        For Each item In s
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", item.Key)

            For Each p In item.Value
                Console.WriteLine("operator first 3 digit {0} {1}", item.Key, p)
            Next

            Console.WriteLine()
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ.

Just assume every numer as a string, which is inturn a `IEnumerable<char>` (`IEnumerable(Of Char)` in VB.NET).

Then you can make a loop through the list of number, apply the `Enumerable.Take(Integer)` function with the value 3 on every element and compare the result (best would be a `select case`) to `811`, `812` and `822`. Then you can assing the current number to the corresponding operator